# How to prove $\dim E=\dim E^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Good afternoon

If $E$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $E^*$ its dual. How to prove $\dim E=\dim E^*$?

I've got this proof:

$\dim E^*=\dim \mathcal{L}(E,F)=\dim E.\dim F=\dim E \qquad(\dim F=1)$

and nothing else!

More generally, is it difficult to prove $\dim \mathcal{L}(E,F)=\dim E.\dim F$ ? ($\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ is a vector space of linear map)

Comment: If you give $E$ and $F$ bases, then $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ corresponds to the space of $m\times n$ matrices, whose dimension is fairly easy to see...

Comment: "More generally, is it difficult to prove dimL(E,F)=dimE.dimF ? (L(E,F) is a vector space of linear map)"?   That depends on how you define "difficult".  That's primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Presumably, you mean "$E$ is finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ a basis of $E$ and define the linear forms $e_j^*$ by

$$e_j^*(e_i)=\delta_{i,j}$$
It's easy to prove that the $(e_j^*)_{1\le j\le n}$ are linearly independent. In fact let $\alpha_j\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_je_j^*=0$$
and we apply it to $e_i$ and we get $\alpha_i=0$. Now let $f\in E^*$ and let $f(e_i)=x_i$. Then $f=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j e_j^*$ because  they are equal on the basis $(e_i)$. Hence $(e_j^*)$ spans $E^*$ and so it's a basis of $E^*$. We conclude that $\dim E^*=n=\dim E$.

Comment: Worth noting $\delta_{ij}=\begin{cases}1&i=j\\0&i\neq j\end{cases}$.

Comment: @user296113 ok, thanks, i need time to assimilate that. See you soon